# Auto Refresh HTML Table every x seconds

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am attempting to refresh a table i have as the variables in there are constantly updated and i want to re-update those variable every few seconds. I have already done up code on my part by giving the table an id and creating a div for it. The code will explain what i actually. Thanks in Advance ! Added Var Table ,Var Refresher, table id is tableID . however the code still wont reload my table !Any ideas??

Test.php

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
     var table = $('#tableID');

    // refresh every 5 seconds


   //    var refresher = setInterval(function() { table.load("refreshable"); }, 5000);
    var refresher = setInterval(table.load.bind(table, "refreshable.php"), 5000);
    //var refresh = setInterval($("#tableID")).load('refreshable.php'),3000);

  setInterval(function() {
      clearInterval(refresher);
    }, 1800000);


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="tableID">
    <?php include_once'refreshable.php'; ?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

refreshable.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
include 'start.php';
include 'functions.php';
header("Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store");

$query = "SELECT * FROM opentrades"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border = '1px' >"; // start a table tag in the HTML
echo "<tr><td>" . "Order Number" . "</td><td>" . "Selection" . "</td><td>" . "Date" . "</td><td>" . "Type" . "</td><td>" . "Size" . "</td><td>" . "Bid Price" . "</td><td>" . "Offer Price" . "</td><td>" ."Stop Loss" . "</td><td>" . "Take Profit" . "</td><td>" ."Profit/Loss(USD)"."</td><td>" ."Close"."</td></tr>" ;  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
if ($row['selection']=='eur/usd')// TO RETRIEVE BID AND OFFER FOR EACH ROW
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid;

      $offerpricepl=$bid1;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/jpy')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid2;

      $offerpricepl=$bid3;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/cad')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid4;

      $offerpricepl=$bid5;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/jpy')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid6;

      $offerpricepl=$bid7;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='eur/chf')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid8;

      $offerpricepl=$bid9;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='gbp/usd')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid10;

      $offerpricepl=$bid11;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='aud/usd')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid12;

      $offerpricepl=$bid13;

      }
  elseif ($row['selection']=='usd/chf')
      {
      $bidpricepl=$bid14;

      $offerpricepl=$bid15;

      }
  if ($row['type']=="buy")
    {

      $minipipskiller='10';
      $offeropen=$row['offerprice'];
      $pips=$offerpricepl-$offeropen;
      $closedb=$offeropen;
      $pips1=round($pips, 6);
      $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);
        if ($pips2<0)
      {
        $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
        $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
      }
      else {
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
      }
      $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;
    }// PIP COUNTING
  elseif ($row['type']=="sell")//FOR PIP COUNTING
    {

      $minipipskiller='10';
      $bidopen=$row['bidprice'];
      $pips=$bidopen-$bidpricepl;
      $closedb=$bidopen;
      $pips1=round($pips, 6);
      $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);
      if ($pips2<0)
      {
        $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
        $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
      }
      else {
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
      }
      $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;
    }



      $ticksize= "0.0001";// FOR PROFIT AND LOSS
      $lot1 = "100000";
      $sizecalc=$row['size'] * $lot1;

        if ($row['type']=="buy")
      { 
        $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
      }
      if ($row['type']=="sell")
      {
        $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
      }

      $zero= '0';

      if($profitandloss<$zero) {
            $profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
        } elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) {
            $profitText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
        }


$sum+= $profitandloss;


    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] .         
        "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . 
        "</td><td>" . $row['date'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['type'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] .
        "</td><td>" . $profitText . 
        "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
        $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
       </td></tr>";  
$profitandloss=0;

if($sum<$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$sum</div>";
} elseif ($sum>$zero) {
    $sumText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$sum</div>";
}
}

echo "</table><br>";



?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does `table.load.bind` do?

Comment: In Firefox or Chrome when you press F12 the console should show. Can you see the xhr requests being made?

Comment: I think the table should be included in test.php, so the `<table border = '1px' id='tableID'>` code never gets reloaded. What you want to reload is the data inside of it. In your Javascript, then you could do something like `$("#tableID").load('refreshable.php');` (of course, the `<table ...>` tag, including `</table>` should be out of refreshable.php).

Comment: @Saurabh it's jquery, it'll make an xhr request and set the innerHTML of the element with the response. JQuery load: http://api.jquery.com/load/ Function.prototype.bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @AlejandroIván Hi, what you mean is i should take out the table tags and add a div in test.php??

Comment: @AlejandroIván what you also mean is that i could change the code to var refresh = setInterval($("#tableID")).load('refreshable.php'),3000);   like that??

Comment: Okay. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier this is what i got . and the uncaught syntaxerror keeps going up each 3 seconds.

Comment: yup i have changed the html part adding the div in , appreciate it if you could review !

Comment: The XHR columns has nothing in it. Same goes for network. There are no respenses or connections.

Comment: in the network it says its not sending anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ajelandro pointed out in the comment you could try to fill a div with the refreshable table:

I've moved the script and added doctype (html5)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tableID">
 <?php include_once'refreshable.php'; ?>
</div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var table = $('#tableID');
     // refresh every 5 seconds
     var refresher = setInterval(function(){
       table.load("refreshable.php");
     }, 5000);
     setTimeout(function() {
       clearInterval(refresher);
     }, 1800000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your php remove the tableID:

```
echo "<table border = '1px'>";
```

Comment: Hi HMR, according to alejandro , i should remove the table tags?

Comment: @nigel Check the Chrome or firefox console as well (repeating myself here) to make sure there are no errors and the xhr requests are made. Press F12 to open, in Firefox (with firebug plugin) XHR request show up in the console tab where you can click on it and inspect it's response. In chrome they do show up in the console tab but you can look in the network tab to inspect the response (you can see get/posted values and request/response headers there as well)

Comment: I edited the code already. It just keep prompting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier every 3 seconds in the error column

Comment: Yup i have reupdated the code and the error has disappeared. In the net work tab , no connection is being made....

Comment: what could be the problem , i shall upload an image if possibel

Comment: uploaded some images for your reference

Comment: @nigel  Cool, I will remove my comments so future users don't have to go through all this. If I'm looking for something I usually read the comments as they contain good info sometimes but this is just a long discusion. Nice to know it works now

Comment: any idea why it cant work in chrome??

Comment: @nigel Works on my chrome on win 7. I can see the xhr request in the console tab as well. Try to set the interval to a shorter time (like one second) you'll see it counting the xhr requests in the console tab. It does only show up once in the network tab as well but after clearing it it doesn't show the new requests. Maybe a bug in your version. I don't use chrome much usually use Firefox with Firebug so don't know all the details of it's debug tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can send AJAX request to refreshable.php and get back results and update your table like:

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = AJAXResponse;
```

Here is an example:

```
var xmlhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

setInterval(function(){

    var xmlhttpObserver;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttpObserver = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttpObserver = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttpObserver.open("POST" , "chat.php" , true);

    xmlhttpObserver.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
         if (xmlhttpObserver.readyState == 4)
         {
             if(xmlhttpObserver.status == 200) 
             {
                 if((xmlhttpObserver.response).length > 4)
                 {
                     responseArea.innerHTML += friendName + ": " + xmlhttpObserver.response;
                 }
             }
             else 
             {
                //alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again #002");
             }
         }
    };
    xmlhttpObserver.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttpObserver.send("sender=" + friendName + "&receiver=" + userName);

} ,6000);
```

Assume that we create these three variables befor:

```
responseArea , friendName , userName
```

I used this code to notify a user that a friend is online.

Comment: @HMR you're right but I just suggest another way to do it, it gives you more control over individual elements.

Comment: so where do i try to put this in the code??

Comment: @nigel I assumed that you already know AJAX. do you?

Comment: yup i do . They say that the AJAXResponse is undefined.

Comment: @nigel Assuming that you have no error you could make it work with minimal changes. Doing the Ajax request yourself would cause bigger changes in your code. The code Amir posted is not to be copied and pasted in your code. It is pseudo code when you would make the Ajax request yourself instead of using JQuery.load. Like $.get, $.post or $.ajax I suggest trying Ajelandro or my solution first as it has mimimal changes to the code you already have. And make sure there are no errors and the ajax requests are made when you call jQuery.load

Comment: Agreed with HMR, but I edit my post and add some code to give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your javascript code.

The `clearTimeout()` method clears a timer set with the `setTimeout()` method.

use `clearInterval(refresher)` instead.